# How to change display property of item with click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website and trying to make a mobile version with a burger menu. The idea is that when the burger is clicked a drop down menu appears. So what I have tried to do is this

HTML:

```
    <nav class="mobile">
        <ul>
            <li id="burgericon"><img src="./images/Icons/burgericon.png" alt="icon" onclick="changeDisplay()"></li>
            <li id="mobilecart"><a href="#cart"><img src="./images/Icons/icon_cart.png" alt="cart"></a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li id="dropdown"><a href="#">Store</a></li>
                    <li id="dropdown"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li id="dropdown"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#burgericon img {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#mobilecart img {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    height: 33px;
    width: 38px;
    float: right;
}

#dropdown {
    display: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
}
```

and JS:

```
function changeDisplay() {
    alert("eys");
    document.getElementbyId("dropdown").style.display = "block";
    }
```

The alert works, but for some reason it won't change the display of that id to block instead of none. Any ideas? I am not allowed to use jQuery yet btw.

Comment: Where have you set it to `"none"`

Comment: the id better to be unique. If you want to change visibility to all the <ul> set the id iside ul tag <ul id='dropdown'> and remove it from the li tags

Comment: You have mistake in getElement it should be getElementById and not getElementbyId

Answer (score 1):

Please notice the Case sensitive in this line:
 `document.getElementById` (notice the capital `B`).

**html**

```
 <ul id="ul">
        <li ><a href="#">Store</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**js**

```
 document.getElementById("ul").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: I'm looking to change it so it can be seen. The display is already set to "none". I want to change it to block.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have an ID once. Move the ID into the `<ul>` element. Also, its `getElementById`, with a capitalized `B`.

```js
function changeDisplay() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#burgericon img {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#mobilecart img {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    height: 33px;
    width: 38px;
    float: right;
}

#dropdown {
    display: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="mobile">
        <ul>
            <li id="burgericon"><a onclick="changeDisplay()">Burger</a></li>
            <li id="mobilecart"><a href="#cart">Cart</a></li>
                <ul  id="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first suggestion i would give is **never use same ids for elements**
and try out this code.

```
 document.getElementById("ul").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the method to how the dropdown worked to show an alternate way. Instead of using JavaScript to affect only one style (i.e. `display`), use multiple classes which in turn controls multiple styles.

- `classList` used to toggle between 2 *states* `.on` and `.off`

  - The `.on` class dictates the dropdown's height and opacity as it grows and fades in.
  - The `.off` class dictates the dropdown's height and opacity as it shrinks and fades out.
- Originally, the `<li>`s each had `#dropdown` ids which is wrong, **ids must always be unique, no exceptions**. So each one now has a class instead (`.dropdown`).

  - Reassigned `#dropdown` to the `<ul>` instead. It is better to target the parent element rather than each of it's children.

**Note:** Normally, a dropdown menu is expected to be able to disappear somehow so this code enures that can happen. Also this function is reusable, and can pass any simple CSS selector.

> #### Signature
>
> `toggleState(target)`
>
> #### Usage
>
> **target:** A string referencing an element. The syntax is exactly like CSS selectors and jQuery objects.
>
> `<ul id="idOfUL">` =  `"#idOfUL"`
>
> `<li class="classOfLI">` = `".classOfLI"`
>
> `<a href="home.html">` = `"a"`

#### SNIPPET

```js
function toggleState(target) {
  var tgt = document.querySelector(target);
  if (tgt.classList.contains('off')) {
    tgt.classList.add('on');
    tgt.classList.remove('off');
  } else {
    tgt.classList.remove('on');
    tgt.classList.add('off');

  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: cyan;
}
img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#burgericon img {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#mobilecart img {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 38px;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}
#dropdown {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.dropdown {
  height: 30px;
}
.off {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out, opacity 1.5s linear .5s;
}
.on {
  max-height: 1500px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: max-height 1.25s ease-in, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<nav class="mobile">
  <ul>
    <li id="burgericon">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-4/128/menu-2-128.png" alt="icon" onclick="toggleState('#dropdown')">
    </li>
    <li id="mobilecart">
      <a href="#cart">
        <img src="http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/20131104_527707eb9746b.png" alt="cart">
      </a>
    </li>
    <ul id='dropdown' class='off'>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Store</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
```